# Continuously monitor the screen for changes in text

Tags: python, screen

I was wondering if it would be possible to monitor the screen for changes in text. For example, take this health bar:[image: health bar] 
This will output:

> Shield: 100
> Health: 100

Or if it saw this:
[image] 
It will return:

> Shield: 82
> Health: 100

Overall, the output I want is something like:

> Shield: 100
> Health: 100 
> Shield: 100
> Health: 100 
> Shield: 100
> Health: 99

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, absolutely it is possible. You can use **PIL.ImageGrab** to take a screenshot of that part of the screen, and **pytesseract** OCR to convert it to a value

You can use something like this:

```
#Import the required libraries
import PIL.ImageGrab
import pytesseract

#INPUT the screen pixel coordinates of a box that surrounds the two numerical values (health and shields)
cropRect = (x1,y1,x2,y2) 

#Grab the screenshot, crop it to the box that you input, and then use OCR to convert the values on the image to a string
values = pytesseract.image_to_string(PIL.ImageGrab.grab().crop(cropRect))

#Use the OCR output to extract the values that you need (using normal string manipulation)
shields = int(values[:values.find("/n")])
health = int(values[values.find("/n")+1:])
print(f"Shields: {shields} Health: {health}")
```

You'll have to check the OCR output to see which character you can use to split the "values" variable (sometimes it can be split with "\n", sometimes  "\t", or "/"). You can check using print(values) to find the proper string separator.

If you want to monitor the values continuously, put it in a while(True) loop (or in a thread of it's own). Something like this:

```
import PIL.ImageGrab
import pytesseract
import time

cropRect = (x1,y1,x2,y2)
while(True):
    values = pytesseract.image_to_string(PIL.ImageGrab.grab().crop(cropRect))
    shields = int(values[:values.find("/n")])
    health = int(values[values.find("/n")+1:])
    print(f"Shields: {shields} Health: {health}")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Man, for a new contributor, this is an amazing answer! I’m going to upvote this.